# 200 Amp Service upgrade Failed Inspection NJ

Tags: electrical-panel

Im a Licensed Contractor and very comfortable with working on electric. That being said, my new home had underground 200 amp service and we could not disconnect the power so I used a licensed electrician to replace the exterior meter box that had rotted and install a new D Square 200 amp QO box (so I didn't have to work with the live 200 amp wires..). I thought he did a fantastic job looked clean and functioned great. Inspector came and Failed it, part one was for not replacing a piece of sheetrock next to the box (I left it off so he could see everything... Easy fix thought). The second Part stated "Multi Wire Circuits 2P CB on a approved tie Bar". I have no idea WTF this means lol. I wire outlets/lights and occasionally add a breaker for a new line. When I asked the inspector what this means he stated that the electrician would understand and it would take him 10 minutes to fix... My electrician bailed on me & won't return phone calls. I'd rather not call in a second electrician for something I'm sure I can fix myself. If anyone has any insight, please let me know.

Side note: All my wires in my house are BX with the exception of one is Romex added years later. My box does not have a separate ground bar in the box instead he tied the neutrals into the left side of the box and tied the grounds into the right. I was thinking the inspector wants a separate ground bar in the box the BX neutrals are fine on the left and the 1 Romex wire he wants that neutral on the Right. I

Breaking down what the Inspector said "Multi Wire Circuits 2P CB on a approved tie Bar" I presume means Multiple wire circuits 2 Pole on Circuit Breaker on approved tie bar? I just don't know what this means needs to happen to fix the problem lol

Thanks in in advance hope I explained this well enough.

Daniel

Comment: Can you post photos of the panels involved?

Comment: Just from the words ""Multi Wire Circuits 2P CB on a approved tie Bar" I think means that the multiwire circuits are on two separate breakers and there must be a metal link (tie bar) that connects the breakers so that you cannot manually turn off only one breaker of a multi-wire pair. electric supply will have the links for the breakers you have.

Comment: @JimStewart not metal. *Listed.* CH ones are plastic and CH beige, naturally :)

Answer (score 3):

Heres my guess.  It's an easy one indeed.   By "multi wire circuit" he actually means **multi-wire branch circuit**.  This is a special method of running 120V circuits where you get 2 circuits' worth of power on one /3 cable, by sharing neutral.   You can google it, but the highlights inspectionwise are

- the circuit must have **neutral pigtailed**, you can't use a receptacle etc. as a splice point for the onward neutral or you'd knock out both sides of the circuit if you removed the device.
- Both legs must, must, must be on opposite poles.
- both legs of the MWBC must have **common maintenance shut-off**, so the usual technique of "turn breakers off until the radio stops playing" turns off the *whole* circuit.

That last one is what you are being written up for.

In a residential breaker panel (as opposed to fuses or industrial), you do that one of two ways.   You use a **2-pole breaker**  (like you would for a water heater, but the correct amperage)... Or you use **listed "handle ties"** that are correct for that breaker type. These are weird and specialty, and big-box rarely carries them.  Sourcing them is such a hassle that I just advise people to use 2-pole breakers, which are sold everywhere for $10. This also leads them into correct decision making when selecting AFCI or GFCI breakers later.

### Where

So you need to search your panel for circuits which have 3 conductors, not including ground: two hots and a neutral.  In a panel like yours with all cables, the dead giveaway is a red wire for the second hot.

Follow each of them, and make sure every one lands on a 2-pole breaker.   If you find a pair going to two singles, measure the voltage at the breaker between the two "hots".  It had better be 240V.  If it's not, congrats, you just dodged a house fire.   Move those two "hots" to a 2-pole breaker of same amp rating.

The reason I advise 2-pole breakers in your case (besides the annoyance of *finding* listed handle ties) is *that way, you don't even need to chase it to figure out if it's an MWBC.  2-pole breaker, done...*

Comment: Amazing to both of you. The vague orange sticker on my box now makes sense lol!  Than you guys very much. Im going to Home depot now to buy a bunch of them and change them out in the morning.

Comment: Just to get one more thing straight, don't 2-pole breakers come in two types--common trip and independent trip? (In the latter type an over-current event at only one breaker trips only that breaker, leaving the other breaker and its circuit still powered.) Both types have common *manual* shutoff. For a multi-wire branch circuit would one want an independent trip or a common trip? What is best practice and what is code on this?

Comment: @JimStewart -- most bog-standard 2-pole breakers are common trip these days, as those are usable everywhere, while independent trip 2-pole breakers are only useful for a limited subset of the times you'd use a 2-pole breaker (they're only good if you either have a single load on the circuit, or are solely powering line-to-neutral aka 120V loads), and can readily be constructed using two 1-pole breakers and a handle tie anyway.  (There are some legacy quadplex part numbers in the Eaton BR line that are independent trip, but that's all I know of)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: From what I've seen, some breakers have powerful enough "trip" springs that if securely tie-barred, a trip on either will shut off both, but not all do.  I would think that having just one side trip would be likely to create a hazardous condition since a momentary high current draw on the non-tripped side could create a significant voltage potential on the "seemingly disconnected" trip side.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: Is there any standard marking to indicate whether connecting two breakers via tie-bar would yield the safe "trip either, trip both" behavior?

Comment: @supercat  accidental common trip of handle-tied breakers *often* happens, like your mashed potato gravy *often* gets into the peas and carrots.  The whole point is that common trip is not guaranteed.   As far as safety, the cases where you imagine it to be unsafe are the cases where it is disallowed.  There, 2-pole common-trip breakers are mandatory, for that very reason! I have become expert on this because I have a glut of 30A 1-pole breakers, which are good for little else.

Comment: @supercat -- there is none, as there are no breakers I know of that can guarantee that behavior with only a handle tie (vs. an internal common trip linkage).  (I suspect that the inability to get a reliable common trip via handle tying is a consequence of the "trip free" behavior required of MCBs by UL 489 and IEC 60947-2.)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: Are you referring to the requirement that holding a handle "on" won't prevent tripping?  I wouldn't think that should be an impediment to having a breaker designed so that the amount of force required to switch it off is sufficiently small that it wouldn't take much force from another breaker to force a "manual" (from the breaker's standpoint) shutoff.

Comment: @supercat -- yeah, that's the requirement I'm referring to -- it means that the tripping mechanism sort of "knocks" the handle to the tripped position as it opens the contacts, and the handle must open/close the contact armature in much the same way, instead of there being a rigid handle-to-armature linkage

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: The breakers I've looked at internally have two mechanisms that must be moved in opposite directions to make contact.  One of them is pushed toward the closed position by the handle when it is switched "off", and is held cocked in that position when the breaker isn't tripped.  The other mechanism can be moved in both directions by the handle, but the handle is spring-loaded toward the "off" position.

Answer (score 1):

In our area two separate one pole breakers properly tied together is no longer acceptable for multiwire circuits.  An actual 2-pole breaker is required.  This breaker is tied together internally thus ensuring that one side cannot be shut-off without the other.  Good Luck.  PCL

Comment: Can you add where your area is? This sounds like a local amendment to me...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I can vouch for PCL. I know of at least three municipalities that have disallowed handle ties and require internally locked  2-pole breakers. Remember it's always up to the AHJ and they really don't like arguing about it.